# How to Query (String, Dictionary<String, String>) into UITableViewCell?

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, dictionary

So I have a variable who's data structure is (String, Dictionary)

```
let audio = Array(self.sharedRec.audioDic) // Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>>
let audioSet = audio[1] // (String, Dictionary<String, String>)
```

So my problem is im having trouble getting the `Dictionary<String, String>` (from `let audioSet = audio[1]`) into another variable.

Here is what `print(audioSet)` shows :

```
("hSmfumVmjkmg9bOYxV67", ["audioString": "/hSmfumVmjkmg9bOYxV67", "audioURL": "/Users/xx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/67D6480B-566D-425B-88AD-E5DECC080337/data/Containers/Data/Application/7091A4BF-9E5F-4957-A3D8-ACE1D160826D/Documents/hSmfumVmjkmg9bOYxV67", "projectTitle": "Gold King", "audioTitle": "Dog"])
```

So I dont need the "hSmfumVmjkmg9bOYxV67" String, but only the dictionary that comes with it into a new variable (so i can iterate through it in my `UITableViewCell`)

Like so :

```
let cell.audioTitle = audioPiece.audioTitle
let cell.audioURL = audioPiece.audioURL
```

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Steve's amazing answer I was about to remove the unwanted keys and get only the dictionaries into a variable.

```
let audio = Array(self.sharedRec.audioDic.values)
self.sharedRec.audioDic = audio
print("Inner Dicitonary Values \(audio)")

// This is what gets printed from above

[["audioString": "/iFDNtXmmvC3lbKPkk2YY", "audioURL": "/Users/xx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/67D6480B-566D-425B-88AD-E5DECC080337/data/Containers/Data/Application/834019D6-5223-47AE-A51E-FFA49FFB14F5/Documents/iFDNtXmmvC3lbKPkk2YY", "projectTitle": "Kash - Oh", "audioTitle": "GOAT"], ["audioString": "/tyddrt0PrrwebN5RBNy2", "audioURL": "/Users/xx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/67D6480B-566D-425B-88AD-E5DECC080337/data/Containers/Data/Application/834019D6-5223-47AE-A51E-FFA49FFB14F5/Documents/tyddrt0PrrwebN5RBNy2", "projectTitle": "Kash - Oh", "audioTitle": "Gold"]]
```

So my question now is How can i iterate through these two or (more later one when there are more dictionaries) and grab their data for my `UITableViewCell`?

I tried - `cell.vocalString.text = audio[0]["audioTitle"]` but it says `Index out of Range`

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I’m understanding your question correctly.  It appears you have a dictionary of dictionaries that you’re first converting into an array, and then subscripting to get one of the inner dictionaries without its "outer key"?  You should be able to create the initial audio array using just the inner dictionary values.  Like this:

```
let audio = Array(self.sharedRec.audioDic.values)
```

Comment: Hey Steve! So you were right and that did work to isolate the inner dictionary values (Please see the update in my post above). Now im trying to make `UITableViewCell` for each `Inner Dictionary` but it doesnt seem to be working.. any thoughts?

Comment: 'audio'  -> Array<Dictionary<String, String>>

Comment: Is is possible the audio array isn't updated yet, when the table view cells are being created?  Maybe surround it with a an 'if audio.count > 0'